# css transform:rotate, rotate forwards not backwards

Tags: css, rotation

I have got the following css:

```
#pie .slice.rot1 {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform:rotate(0deg);
        -m-transform:rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform:rotate(0deg);
        -transform:rotate(0deg);

}
#pie .slice.rot2 {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(52.5deg); 
        -moz-transform:rotate(52.5deg);
        -m-transform:rotate(52.5deg);
        -o-transform:rotate(52.5deg);
        -transform:rotate(52.5deg);

}
#pie .slice.rot3 {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(104deg); 
        -moz-transform:rotate(104deg); 
        -m-transform:rotate(104deg); 
        -o-transform:rotate(104deg); 
        transform:rotate(104deg); 

}
#pie .slice.rot4 {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(154.5deg); /* (360 / 7) * 3 = 51.5 */
        -moz-transform:rotate(154.5deg); /* (360 / 7) * 3 = 51.5 */
        -m-transform:rotate(154.5deg); /* (360 / 7) * 3 = 51.5 */
        -o-transform:rotate(154.5deg); /* (360 / 7) * 3 = 51.5 */
        transform:rotate(154.5deg); /* (360 / 7) * 3 = 51.5 */
}
#pie .slice.rot5 {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(204deg); /* (360 / 7) * 4 = 51.5 */
        -moz-transform:rotate(204deg); /* (360 / 7) * 4 = 51.5 */
        -m-transform:rotate(204deg); /* (360 / 7) * 4 = 51.5 */
        -o-transform:rotate(204deg); /* (360 / 7) * 4 = 51.5 */
        transform:rotate(204deg); /* (360 / 7) * 4 = 51.5 */
}
#pie .slice.rot6 {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(254.5deg); /* (360 / 7) * 5 = 51.5 */
        -moz-transform:rotate(254.5deg); /* (360 / 7) * 5 = 51.5 */
        -m-transform:rotate(254.5deg); /* (360 / 7) * 5 = 51.5 */
        -o-transform:rotate(254.5deg); /* (360 / 7) * 5 = 51.5 */
        transform:rotate(254.5deg); /* (360 / 7) * 5 = 51.5 */
}
#pie .slice.rot7 {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(307deg); /* (360 / 7) * 6 = 51.5 */
        -moz-transform:rotate(307deg); /* (360 / 7) * 6 = 51.5 */
        -m-transform:rotate(307deg); /* (360 / 7) * 6 = 51.5 */
        -o-transform:rotate(307deg); /* (360 / 7) * 6 = 51.5 */
        transform:rotate(307deg); /* (360 / 7) * 6 = 51.5 */
}
```

What this does is basically, rotates an image depending on which section / div you click in.

My image is currently a circle, with 7 sections. When i load my page up the class .rot1 is already selected. when i select .rot2 the image will rotate 52.5deg and vice-versa.

My problem is when i get to .rot7 at 360deg, and then click on .rot1, rather than the image rotating forward to 0deg, it will back backwards and rotate -360deg.

Any idea on how i can make it rotate forwards and not backwards?

Cheers,
Dan

Comment: Can you provide some jsFiddle with html too.

Comment: You can make .rot1 rotate(360), but I don't think that's what you want, but at some point its going to have to rotate backwards to get back to 0, are you trying to make it always rotate in one direction?

Comment: @Gimmy, this is not ran by JS

Comment: @watson yes exactly that, i want it to go in one direction only.

Comment: does it work with negative value's? like -360deg

Comment: You need to use javascript to get the previous rotation and then add 51.5 degrees to it, and update css.

Comment: BTW, jsFiddle is not just for JS and would be useful here.

Answer (score 0):

I have choose to do that using a class for the rotation and another for the transition.
And to make it easier in the script, using 2 divs nested so that you have only one class in each.

The HTMl

```
<div id="pie" class="rotate">
<div id="pos" class="rot0">
<div class="rot0" onclick="myFunction(0)">1</div>
<div class="rot6" onclick="myFunction(1)">2</div>
<div class="rot5" onclick="myFunction(2)">3</div>
<div class="rot4" onclick="myFunction(3)">4</div>
<div class="rot3" onclick="myFunction(4)">5</div>
<div class="rot2" onclick="myFunction(5)">6</div>
<div class="rot1" onclick="myFunction(6)">7</div>
```

The CSS

```
#pie {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
left: 35px;
top: 35px;
position: absolute;
background-color: papayawhip;
border-radius: 50%;
}

#pos div {
    background-color: lightblue;
left: 0px;
top: 100px;    
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
position: absolute;
-webkit-transform-origin: 100px 0px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

#pos {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#pie .rot0 {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
    -transform:rotate(0deg);
}
#pie .rot1 {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(52.5deg); 
    -transform:rotate(52.5deg);

}
#pie .rot2 {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(104deg); 
    transform:rotate(104deg); 
}
#pie .rot3 {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(154.5deg); 
    transform:rotate(154.5deg); 
}
#pie .rot4 {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(204deg); 
    transform:rotate(204deg); 
}
#pie .rot5 {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(254.5deg); /* (360 / 7) * 5 = 51.5 */
    transform:rotate(254.5deg); /* (360 / 7) * 5 = 51.5 */
}
#pie .rot6 {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(307deg); /* (360 / 7) * 6 = 51.5 */
    transform:rotate(307deg); /* (360 / 7) * 6 = 51.5 */
}


.rotate1 {
    -webkit-animation: circle1 2s 1 linear;    
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
@-webkit-keyframes circle1 {
    from {-webkit-transform: rotateZ(-52.5deg)}
    to {-webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg)}
}

.rotate2 {
-webkit-animation: circle2 4s 1 linear;    
-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
@-webkit-keyframes circle2 {
from {-webkit-transform: rotateZ(-104deg)}
to {-webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg)}
}

.rotate3 {
-webkit-animation: circle3 6s 1 linear;    
-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
@-webkit-keyframes circle3 {
from {-webkit-transform: rotateZ(-154.5deg)}
to {-webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg)}
}

.rotate4 {
-webkit-animation: circle4 8s 1 linear;    
-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
@-webkit-keyframes circle4 {
from {-webkit-transform: rotateZ(-204deg)}
to {-webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg)}
}

.rotate5 {
-webkit-animation: circle5 10s 1 linear;    
-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
@-webkit-keyframes circle5 {
from {-webkit-transform: rotateZ(-254deg)}
to {-webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg)}
}
.rotate6 {
-webkit-animation: circle6 12s 1 linear;    
-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
@-webkit-keyframes circle6 {
from {-webkit-transform: rotateZ(-307deg)}
to {-webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg)}
}
```

And the JavaScript

```
var pos=0;

function myFunction(newpos) {
 var delta=newpos-pos;
 if (delta < 0) { delta = delta + 7;}
 pos=newpos;
 document.getElementById("pos").className="rot"+newpos;
 document.getElementById("pie").className="rotate"+delta;
 document.getElementById("pie").addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', function(){
this.className='';
}, false);

}
```

## [Demo for webkit](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/W8vMW/)